# ggplot2 is plotting a line strangely

Tags: r, ggplot2

i am trying to plot the time series x_t = A + (-1)^t B

To do this i am using the following code. The problem is, that the ggplot is wrong.

```
require (ggplot2)
set.seed(42)
N<-2
A<-sample(1:20,N)
B<-rnorm(N)
X<-c(A+B,A-B)
dat<-sapply(1:N,function(n) X[rep(c(n,N+n),20)],simplify=FALSE)
dat<-data.frame(t=rep(1:20,N),w=rep(A,each=20),val=do.call(c,dat))

ggplot(data=dat,aes(x=t, y=val, color=factor(w)))+
  geom_line()+facet_grid(w~.,scale = "free")
```

[image]

looking at the head of dat everything looks right:

```
> head(dat)
  t  w     val
1 1 12 10.5533
2 2 12 13.4467
3 3 12 10.5533
4 4 12 13.4467
5 5 12 10.5533
6 6 12 13.4467
```

So the lower (blue) line should only have values 10.5533 and 13.4467. But it also takes different values. What is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I don't get that plot using your example. Also, the data your example produces has duplicated `t` values for each point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should be more careful before asserting that something is "wrong". The way you are creating `dat` the rows are not ordered by `dat$t`, so `head(...)` is not displaying the extra values:

```
head(dat[order(dat$w,dat$t),],10)
#    t  w      val
# 21 1 18 18.43530
# 61 1 18 18.36313
# 22 2 18 19.56470
# 62 2 18 17.63687
# 23 3 18 18.43530
# 63 3 18 18.36313
# 24 4 18 19.56470
# 64 4 18 17.63687
# 25 5 18 18.43530
# 65 5 18 18.36313
```

Note the row numbers.